# SOLR - Processing query response

Tags: java, solr, response

I am new to `SOLR` and Java as well. My question may be very basic. I am trying to write a java client for `SOLR` - do I need a `SOLR` response `XSD` to generate Java classes and process `SOLR` query response.

How is an `SOLR` response usually processed in practice?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use SolrJ?

Comment: I can certainly use SolrJ...I just wanted to explore options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for XSD. For a basic way to query Solr, your client can access the Solr REST interface. It can return JSON, and you can parse it as explained here:

[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

In practice, the query response is often processed in Javascript or some other language.